# Lodash debounce error: Uncaught TypeError: Expected a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lodash, react-functional-component, debouncing

I am trying to use the `debounce` function to avoid multiple calls when I'm typing and searching something in a table. This is what I have done -

```
onChange={(_event, searchText) => React.useCallback(debounce(void setSearchText(searchText), _searchDebounceWaitTime), [])}
```

It gives an error stating `Uncaught TypeError: Expected a function`
What am I doing wrong ? Most solutions I found online  have done a similar thing.

Note: I also tried doing -

```
onChange={(_event, searchText) => React.useCallback(debounce(searchText => setSearchText(searchText), _searchDebounceWaitTime), [])}
```

but this time I got the following error - `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:`

Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as the error states, a react hook cannot be in the jsx. It should be like this:

```
const onChange = React.useCallback((_event, searchText) => setSearchText(searchText), [])

//...
return (
  <Component
    //...
    onChange={onChange}
  />
);
```

Then, for a debounce, what you are looking for is a memoized function:

```
const onChange = React.useMemo(() => debounce((_event, searchText) => setSearchText(searchText), _searchDebounceWaitTime), [])
```

Comment: Could you explain why is it that for debounce we need a memoized function ?